# Converting a string to date-time format

Tags: powershell, date

I am importing a csv to an excel using powershell. Both of my columns have date-time in the following format:

`2019-01-25T19:58:28.000Z`

I want to convert the column to the following format `"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm"`

I tried the following two things and none of them worked:
`[datetime]::ParseExact($fullinfo.A, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm", $null)`

`$excel.Columns.item('b').NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm"`

```
$fullInfoSheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$fullInfoSheet.cells.item(1,1) = "Column A" 
$fullInfoSheet.cells.item(1,2) = "Column B" 

$fullinfolist = Import-Csv -Path $csvfullFile -Header A, B

$i = 2 

foreach($fullinfo in $fullinfolist) 
{ 
 $fullInfoSheet.cells.item($i,1) = [datetime]::ParseExact($fullinfo.A, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm", $null) 
 $fullInfoSheet.cells.item($i,2) = $fullinfo.B 
 $i++ 
}

$excel.Columns.item('b').NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces output in your desired format

```
$InputDate = '2019-01-25T19:58:28.000Z'

get-date $InputDate -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm'
```

Comment: Thank you. do you know how put am/pm in this format?

Comment: I'm not on my PC to test but I think you add ' tt' to the format string